# Problem viewing network on Nautilus

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

Windows machines are able to see shared folders on my Ubuntu machines but the Ubuntu machines cannot consistently see any other machines through Nautilus.  Under Browse Network, it shows the local machine, my WIFI service, and the Windows Network.  When I open the Windows Network, it shows the workgroup icon.  When I open the workgroup icon, it shows the local machine and my WIFI service again.  I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  After searching everywhere I could think of with no success, I found that if I run:

```
sudo service nmbd restart
```

in Terminal whenever Nautilus gets stuck, it is sometimes able to find shared folders again... until it gets stuck and I have to repeat the process  I don't know why it works, and it's not consistent.  But frequently it seems to fix the problem temporarily.

As suggested in some of the posts I read, I've tried changing the workgroup name to all caps. and I added a netbios name, also all caps. to the /etc/samba/smb.conf file to no avail.

I can get Nautilus to see the machines if I use Connect to Server under the file menu and type the local IP address.  I can also see them if I run

```
nautilus smb://[IP address]
```

in the Terminal.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a configuration issue with the file /etc/samba/smb.conf on the machine with the shared directory. Add the following lines at the end of the Browsing/Identification section of smb.conf ...

```
netbios name = <hostname>
name resolve order = wins bcast lmhosts host
client lanman auth = yes
client ntlmv2 auth = no
```

The hostname of the server can be found by typing hostname at a terminal. After making the changes to smb.conf, restart the smbd and nmbd services (sudo service xxxx restart), and see if the share will show up in nautilus ok.

This tip from
http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=270346